# Install specfic package version on centos using yum

Tags: linux, docker, centos, dockerfile, yum

How do I install specific version of a package via yum on centos 8?

I'm creating a dockerfile that needs:

- maven
- kubectl
- git
- helm

I want to install them using yum; however, `yum install [packagename] did not do the trick for maven. I also need to install specific version of the aforementioned packages.

Errors I got:

```
Error: Nothing to do
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install maven-3.6.3' returned a non-zero code: 1

Error: Nothing to do
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install maven@3.6.3' returned a non-zero code: 1

The command '/bin/sh -c yum install maven' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:centos-slim

RUN yum install maven-3.6.3

CMD [""]
```

Comment: btw, why are you including `/bin/sh -c` in the command, it should work without it

Comment: I'm not specifying it, the error messages just shows it as well.

Comment: try using `sudo`

Comment: It wasn't the sudo but I was doing something silly when using dockerfile multiline for kubectl installation on centos 8. But your answer to my question is correct.

Comment: Happy you fixed the problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `sudo yum install <package_name>-<version_info>` to install a certain package version, and `sudo yum downgrade <package_name>-<version_info>` to downgrade to a certain version.

Edit: Try to use `sudo` if this does not work.

Comment: if this is the correct answer, would you mind marking mine as the correct one (click the check mark)

Comment: As you can see the first error method, it did not work for maven; in fact, the dockerfile I put up has that. Not sure why. kubectl also requires multiline configuration before yum install, which I'm struggling with.